# How to change value of V-Snackbar after timeout

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I use vuex and a snackbar.js and Snackbar.vue.
When I click submit button from a component, It activates the popup value in vuex store. If PopUpDialog===true then Snackbar.vue appears on the top. But the problem is that Although the snackbar disappears after 2000duration but the popup value remains true. Hence, I cannot call the snackbar anymore.

```
<template>
   <v-snackbar
      :timeout="timeout"
      top
      :color=popup_type
      outlined
      right
    >
     {{popup_message}}
    </v-snackbar>
</template>
<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  export default
  {
    data() 
    {
        return{        
          timeout:2000
        }
    },
   
    computed: mapGetters({     
      popup :'GETTER_POPUP_VALUE',      
      popup_message:'GETTER_POPUP_MESSAGE',
      popup_type:'GETTER_POPUP_TYPE'
    }),   
  }
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

From the first component, I call the snackbar like this;

```
 <pop-up v-if="this.PopUpDialog === true"></pop-up>
```

And

```
//HERE I call Snackbar
             this.$store.dispatch('SET_POPUP_VALUE',true);
             this.$store.dispatch('SET_POPUP_TYPE','error');
             this.$store.dispatch('SET_POPUP_MESSAGE','Listeleme için en az bir kriter girilmelidir. (140)');
```

I couldn't understand WHEN and WHERE should I change the value of PopUpDialog.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved like that;

```
<template>
       <v-snackbar
          :timeout="timeout"
          top
          :value="popup"
          @input="snackbarClose"
          :color=popup_type
          outlined
          right
        >
         {{popup_message}}
        </v-snackbar>
    </template> 
    methods: {
          snackbarClose(val) {
            this.$store.dispatch("SET_POPUP_VALUE", val)
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `v-model` for snackbar.